# Using fancyhdr package... Header and Page Number missing for few pages in one chapter

Tags: fancyhdr

I am writing my thesis. The problem is that the chapter header and page numbers are not showing in chapter 6 for a few pages. I am completely clueless about why it is happening? Please rectify my mistake.
My Thesis template is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside]{ducs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[lined,linesnumbered,ruled,resetcount,longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,french,italian,welsh,greek,russian,portuguese,spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[tablename=Table]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\newcommand{\nextnr}{\stepcounter{AlgoLine}\ShowLn}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\algrenewcommand\textproc{}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[black-square]{QED}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={small, singlespacing}}
%\usepackage {subcaption}
\usepackage{psfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{psfig}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5in, right=1.1in, top=1.0in, bottom=.90in]{geometry}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % important if your docs contain special characters
\usepackage{epstopdf}%
\usepackage{units} % for solidus fractions %
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float, caption}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=.2em}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{lscape} 
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\newcommand{\nextnr}{\stepcounter{AlgoLine}\ShowLn}
\newcommand\dunderline[3][-1pt]{{%
\setbox0=\hbox{#3}
\ooalign{\copy0\cr\rule[\dimexpr#1-#2\relax]{\wd0}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\maketitle
cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 1 }}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % This makes the page numbers Roman (i, ii, etc)
\include{chapter1_T7}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 2 }}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter2}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 3}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter3_T1} 
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 4}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter4_T2}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 5}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\newpage
\include{chapter5_T2}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 6 }}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter6_T3}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
%\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 7}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter7_T2}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 8 }}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter8_T2}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Chapter 9 Conclusion}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\include{chapter9}
\newpage 
\cleardoublepage
{\normalsize
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\scriptsize \textit{Bibliography}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{references}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

I have included extra packages to know whether any of these packages contradicts with 'fancyhdr' package.

Comment: I don't think there's another package that conflicts fancyhdr. You shouldn't redefine \fancypagestyle for each chapter. It should be defined once and for all in the preamble

Comment: Ok, Bernard. Rectified but the problem still persists. Thanks!

Comment: You load packages I never heard of (`psfig`),  others that conflict (`subfig` and `subcaption`), although unrelated to headers, obsolete ones, that shouldn't be used any more (`epsfig`, simply replaced with `graphicx`). You should first make your preamble clean.

Comment: Bernard, these packages are included in the latex template, I haven't explicitly included any of these. The problem I am facing is only in chapter 6 where the first three pages are showing the headers and page numbers. The Rest of the chapter is without page numbers and headers. From Chapter 7 onwards, there is no such problem.

Comment: Just in case: comment all commands from `fancyhdr` and uncomment loading of  `titlesec`, add the  `[pagestyles]` option and define a \newpagestyle ' (see the `titleps` documentation.

Comment: There is no **the LaTeX template**.  Templates are written by people who often have no idea what they are doing.  Never copy a template without reading the manuals of every package used!

Comment: John, I request you to comment only on the asked question. Your comment seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I am trying your solution and will update soon.